# Families of simple modules over semisimple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

Within my abstract algebra lecture we came across a theorem stating that for any ring $R$ and any $R$-module $M$ which is the sum of a family of simple submodules $(U_i)_{i\in I}$, i.e. $M=\sum_{i\in I}U_i$ we can show that for any simple submodule $N\le M$ we find a finite subset $J\subseteq I$ so that $N\cong U_j$ for every $j\in J$ (this is reasonably easy to prove) and $N\le\bigoplus_{j\in J}U_j$.

The proof goes as follows:

Seeing that $N$ is simple, it is given by $Ru$ for any $u\in N\setminus\{0\}$. Now since $u\in M$, there is a finite linear combination $u=\sum_{j\in J}u_j,\,u_j\in U_j\setminus\{0\},\, J$ finite. That implies the fact that $N=Ru\subseteq \sum_{j\in J}Ru_j=\sum_{j\in J}U_j$. Now we can look at the projection mapping $\pi_j\colon N\to U_j,\,ru\mapsto ru_j$ which is a non trivial homomorphism between simple modules, i.e. an isomorphism.

Thus far I can follow quite nicely. However, we do not address the problem of the above sum being direct. In general it is simply false to say that any sum of simple modules is direct already, so how come it is true in this example? Can anyone explain?

Comment: *In general it is simply false to say that any sum of simple modules is direct already, so how come it is true in this example?* . To paraphase: "it is not always true... why is it true here?"  I'm not sure what you're hoping to get at with this question. Sometimes the sum of two simple modules is direct. Sometimes it is not.  Are you under the misapprehension that if something sometimes does not happen, it never happens?

Comment: Check the title, and the post, as well. I assume the last word of the title should be "rings". But then in the post, you do not say anything about the ring being semisimple.

Comment: I first thought it would be genereally true, that sums of simple modules are always direct, until I was shown a counterexample (which is actually really easy to find, I was just confused). Thats why I posted the question that particular way. So no, I don't assume that it's genereally false, but I cannot see why it would be true here.

Comment: As to the semisimple, isn't any module which can be written as a sum of simple submodules, semisimple? Meaning that my title indeed is correct. I am not looking for semi simple rings here, that would be too much to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is reasonably straight forward if one actually uses the fact that the given $R$-module is semisimple: Because of that we can assume WLOG that the given sum is direct already, which makes the question trivial.